# R, Plotting points with Labels on a single (horizontal) numberline

Tags: r, plot

For educational purpose I'm trying to plot a singel horizontal "numberline" with some datapoints with labels in R. I came this far;

```
library(plotrix)
source("spread.labels.R")
plot(0:100,axes=FALSE,type="n",xlab="",ylab="")
axis(1,pos=0) 
spread.labels(c(5,5,50,60,70,90),rep(0,6),ony=FALSE, 
labels=c("5","5","50","60","70","90"), 
offsets=rep(20,6))
```

This gave me a numberline with smaller lines pointing up to (and a little bit "in") the labels from where the datapoints should lie on the numberline - but without the points itself. Can anyone give me additional or alternative R-codes for solving thess problems:
- datapoints itself still missing are not plotted, 
- and labels maybe not evenly divided over the whole numberline, 
- and lines come into the labels and not merely point to the labels

Thank a lot,

Benjamin Telkamp

Comment: First, this code is not reproducible. Second, this sounds like it might be easier for others to help you if you upload a picture of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually like to create plots using primitive base R graphics functions, such as [`points()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/points.html), [`segments()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/segments.html), [`lines()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/lines.html), [`abline()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/abline.html), [`rect()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/rect.html), [`polygon()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/polygon.html), [`text()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/text.html), and [`mtext()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/mtext.html). You can easily create curves (e.g. for circles) and more complex shapes using `segments()` and `lines()` across granular coordinate vectors that you define yourself. For example, see [Plot angle between vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31894079/plot-angle-between-vectors/31898410#31898410). This provides much more control over the plot elements you create, however, it often takes more work and careful coding than more "pre-packaged" solutions, so it's a tradeoff.

For your case, it sounds to me like you're happy with what `spread.labels()` is trying to do, you just want the following changes:

1. add point symbols at the labelled points.
2. prevent overlap between labels and lines.

Here's how this can be done:

```
## define plot data
xlim <- c(0,100);
ylim <- c(0,100);
px <- c(5,5,50,60,70,90);
py <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0);
lx.buf <- 5;
lx <- seq(xlim[1]+lx.buf,xlim[2]-lx.buf,len=length(px));
ly <- 20;

## create basic plot outline
par(xaxs='i',yaxs='i',mar=c(5,1,1,1));
plot(NA,xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,axes=F,ann=F);
axis(1);

## plot elements
segments(px,py,lx,ly);
points(px,py,pch=16,xpd=NA);
text(lx,ly,px,pos=3);
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Beautiful, I played around with the values, so I also understand to change and generalize this. Bgoldst, thank you so much! Benjamin

Comment: How do I change the amount of points? also I am setting my xlim to c(0,923) but the nubmer line only goes to 800!!!!!